# Getting a RunTime Exception when accessing FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, exception, runtime, android-framelayout

So I'm writing an app, and for some reason I get a Runtime exception when I try to get the height of a FrameLayout. I use weight quite a bit throughout the design, so I wanted to double check they were the height I needed them to be.

Here is my main Activity:

```
package com.app.conekta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Conekta extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        FrameLayout fl1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.headerFrameLayout);
        //Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        Toast.makeText(Conekta.this, fl1.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

And this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:background="#597eAA" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#7ba1d1"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_conekta" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bodyLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftBlankFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:background="#f3f3f3" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/centerVerticalLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/topCenterFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.35" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venueLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.025"
                android:text="What are you looking for?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/venueTextField"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.025" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/middleCenterFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.05" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.025"
                android:text="Where?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/locationTextField"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.025"
                android:text="" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttonLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.05"
                android:background="#f3f3f3"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/leftButtonLinearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:background="#6fa8dc"
                    android:text="Search" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rightButtonLinearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1" >
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomCenterFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.35" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/rightBlankFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:background="#f3f3f3" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:background="#7ba1d1" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

```
11-16 23:57:41.408: W/ResourceType(409): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
11-16 23:57:41.427: D/AndroidRuntime(409): Shutting down VM
11-16 23:57:41.427: W/dalvikvm(409): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-16 23:57:41.427: E/AndroidRuntime(409): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.conekta/com.app.conekta.Conekta}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:200)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.app.conekta.Conekta.onStart(Conekta.java:27)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3723)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
11-16 23:57:41.447: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  ... 11 more
11-16 23:57:41.467: I/dalvikvm(409): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
11-16 23:57:41.467: E/dalvikvm(409): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(Conekta.this, String.valueOf(fl1.getHeight()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @user370305 Do you know why now it returns a 0? I understand that i might call getHeight too early so I even moved it to onStart, but I still get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
Toast.makeText(Conekta.this, fl1.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(Conekta.this, String.valueOf(fl1.getHeight()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if it's correct. You can do so by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.